# Copy Last Row and Paste to new document

Tags: vba, copy, paste

I have the below code to try and copy the last row of data when submitted from one worksheet and open and paste to a new worksheet on a new row. Everytime I run this it copies all the rows on the whole database and not just the last row. When I run it again it does find the last row on the new document and paste there it is just the copy part not working. Can anyone help?

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\FOH Manager\OneDrive - Bespoke Hotels 2\Carnoustie\Reservations\Golf 2024\Confirmations 2024\Auto Confirmations.xlsx"


Dim lCopyLastRow As Integer
Dim lDestLastRow As Integer
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet

Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Booking Details")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("Auto Confirmations.xlsx").Worksheets("Data")

lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row


    wsCopy.Range("A1:AD" & lCopyLastRow).Copy
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

To copy last row on on worksheet and copy and paste on to new worksheet

Comment: change this: "wsCopy.Range("A1:AD" & lCopyLastRow).Copy" to this: "wsCopy.Range("A" & lCopyLastRow & ":AD" & lCopyLastRow).Copy"